# Creating an expandable column that depends on another columns result

Tags: sharepoint-online

So I've looked up quite a bit for the best way to do this in sharepoint online and I can't seem to pinpoint the solution to accomplish this, what I'm trying to do is simplify the HR process and I can't seem to figure out how to BEST make this work, I know I can create a 2nd column that's "always there", but what I want is to have my column that basically says "will (username) be needing a new computer as well?"

From there, IN THE SAME FORM I want to have a column that only shows up if yes was selected in the question just previous (the column I referred to above), I don't even know if there's a way to make that column appear only if yes was selected on the previous column.

Another great way that I don't know how to do this would be to have the column validation formula specify a list of choices that user can select depending on which answer they selected in a specific column, but I can't seem to think of how I can accomplish this.

Can anyone assist me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into [CSR - Client Side Rendering](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) (=Javacript Front-end development) and customize how the columns are displayed on the New/Edit Form

- Hide your second column by default ([CSR Example #9](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-a52cf8a7))
- Show it when Yes in another column is selected

Your option to make the column validation formula present a list of options will not work as Validation only returns a true/false and displays a text. It can't do anything with other objects in the page.